# script error in web browser

Tags: vb.net

i have made a web browser in vb.net.but for few pages i find a msgbox displaying script error.

```
script error
  ! an error has occured in the script on this page
  line: 86
  char: 3
  error: object expected
  code: 0
  url: http://songs.pk/


     do you want to continue running scripts on this page?
            yes   no
```

or u can see the screen shot here http://dharmatejanaishadham.blogspot.com/
but still i'm able to open that page.is there a way by which i can avoid this script error.

Answer (score 0):

songs.pk website has a number of unsafe JavaScript executions. All of these are from the ads you have placed on your site. These ads scripts are calling methods on your domain.  This is a cross-domain request and unsafe. Get yourself FireFox and and install the FireBug extension on it. You will then see each of the error in detail and the source of it.

The error message is shown to you by the browser to avoid freezing itself by continue to execute these script. It is a good thing to catch bad script executions.